# Remove event listener on rerender React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, listener

I'm collecting mouse position events in an array once a button has been toggled. I only want the array to be logged to me once the button is toggled again.

I am using an event listener for `mousedown` that automatically removes itself if the button is pressed (and sets the state of a hook variable to false).

I have a useEffect that depends on 2 props I pass in, that on change cause the page to re-render. Bear in mind that it re-renders on *any* of the dependent props changing. This could be random.

My issue is that my event listeners don't seem to be being deleted in time, and multiple instances of them are firing at the same time after re-render.

What can I do to ensure only 1 event listener is active at the time I want it?

```js
const twoDArray: number[][] = [];

element.addEventListener('mousedown', function addToArray(e) {
   if (statefulBooleanVariable && twoDArray.length < 64) {
     twoDArray.push([e.clientX, e.clientY]);
     return;
   } else if (!statefulBooleanVariable && twoDArray.length > 0) {
     element.removeEventListener('mousedown', addToArray);
     console.log(twoDArray);
   }
});
```

For some reason, this causes some sort of propagation that `e.stopPropagation()` is making no difference to. Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you add (and remove) event listeners directly during your render function is run. This will cause trouble. React can run render as many times as it likes, aborting it, or to completion as it likes. Don't perform side effects inside render. Use a `useEffect` or some event.

Comment: Thanks @Martin and Konrad, looks as if I just didn't look hard enough - thanks!